# Server-side APi calls render Django + react

Tags: django, reactjs, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on React SPA, using Django as backend and Django REST Framework for making an API - so Django makes some text data (via models registered on the admin page), sends it to API and React collects it like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/main');
        const MainPage = await res.json();
        this.setState({MainPage})
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

So API call actually happens on client side and I wonder: how is it possible to render API call on the server side using Django? What are the approaches and best practices?

Should I use Node server too, or just Django is enough?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `to render API call on the server side` ? An API can be called, but it cannot be rendered like a template.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood the concept. Fetches take some time and I wondered if there is a way to optimise them using server-side magic

Comment: yes send them in as props to the component and do data loading if they arent there already, then use for example https://github.com/markfinger/python-react to render serverside